# Go through all outbound contacts

Tags: web8, outbound-email, contact-sync

Some of the rows in `[Tridion_submgmt].[dbo].[CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS]` have incorrect encoding for certain extended details columns.
For example & #193; instead of Á

Same issue is in `[Tridion_cm_email_Prod].[dbo].[CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS]` but using Audience Manager API it is possible to update rows.

Wrong encoding in CD db is preventing synchronization of existing contacts between CM and CD.

It is necessary to write a code which will go through all Outbound email contacts and update them.

Any help to get all contacts from `[Tridion_submgmt].[dbo].[CONTACTS_EXTENDED_DETAILS]` using .net code?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The API on the CD side only allows you to update a single Contact.
Any bulk updates you need to do should happen on the CM side and be synchronized.

I know you said your synchronization is broken, but despite what it may seem -- it's actually valid to have those characters in a field (just probably not what you meant to save). My synchronization works fine with such characters, so I think something else might be going on.

So you should work with customer support to solve the synchronization issue you are experiencing. A hotfix may be required if it turns out to be a product issue.

Once synchronization is working again, you can use the CM API to update the affected Contacts and fix the characters to be what you want / need - either through bulk export+import (which I would recommend) or updating each Contact one at a time (will be slow).

As Chris pointed out, you should never update the database yourself as you can easily mess things up in subtle ways that will be nigh impossible to troubleshoot later on.

Answer (score 1):

Look for an API update solution, if is not recommended to update any Tridion database unless directed to by SDL or you may invalidate your support.

Comment: Yes, I achieved it by updating contact by contact using api on cd side, finding contact by tcm uri and it works.  I thought there might be some API to get all contacts.